# Null returns for distance

Tags: mysql

Total SQL newb here. I've created two SQL tables, one containing information about hotels and the other containing information about attractions. I'm trying to create a query where I can input a postcode of an attraction, and have the database return the distance of hotels within a 1, 5 and 10 mile radius.

```
SELECT 
   hotels.*, 
   attractions.*,  
   ( ( ACOS( SIN(hotels.Hotel_Lat                                  * PI() / 180) 
           * SIN(attractions.Attraction_Lat                        * PI() / 180)
         +   
             COS(hotels.Hotel_Long                                 * PI() / 180)
           * COS(attractions.Attraction_Long                       * PI() / 180)
           * COS((hotels.Hotel_Long - attractions.Attraction_Long) * PI() / 180)
           ) * 180 / PI()
     ) * 60 * 1.1515
   ) as distance  
FROM hotels 
JOIN attractions
```

This query returns 'Null' for distances. My tables are populated with lat longs as well as postcodes. Any ideas why please? I have negative value longitudes if that makes a difference?

Using MySQL Community server 5.6.17.

Sample Data - There are 7 rows of data in hotels.

```
Hotel_Name | Hotel_Address | Hotel_Lat | Hotel_Long
a            ST158DH        52.906438    -2.145523
b            ST161LF        52.827959    -2.129709

Attraction_Name | Attraction_Postcode | Attraction_Lat | Attraction_Long
a                   ST180BA              52.839509        -2.056964
b                   ST180TG              52.832820        -2.091124
```

There are four attractions in total.

Comment: Try to debug this by selecting each factor separately. I guess one of the factors is null.

Comment: Please show sample data or better yet, but an example up on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it properly.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tHPKiLJ

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rFYVXEE.png

Comment: You are getting NULL as the result of attempting to take ACOS of a number > 1.00. This is because the left and right terms of the sum for your sample datasets are approximately 0.79 and 0.99, yielding a sum of nearly 1.8.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Is there anything I can change to make it work Pieter?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), which is well behaved even at very small distances, try this code (or equivalent for MySQL):

```
select
     Hotel_Name
    ,Hotel_Address
    ,Attraction_Name
    ,Attraction_Address

    ,round(2 * atn2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a)),                       4) as DeltaRad 
    ,round(2 * atn2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a)) * (180.0 / pi()),      2) as DeltaDeg 
    ,round(2 * atn2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a)) * (180.0 / pi()) * 60, 2) as DeltaNMs 
    ,round(2 * atn2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a)) * 6371.0,              2) as DeltaKMs 
from (
  select 
       Hotel_Name
      ,Hotel_Address
      ,Attraction_Name
      ,Attraction_Address

      , SinHalfDeltaLatRad * SinHalfDeltaLatRad
      + CosCosLat 
      * SinHalfDeltaLngRad * SinHalfDeltaLngRad       as a
  from (
    SELECT 
        Hotel_Name
       ,Hotel_Address
       ,Attraction_Name
       ,Attraction_Address

       ,sin((h.Lat - a.Lat) * PI() / 180.0 / 2.0) as SinHalfDeltaLatRad  
       ,sin((h.Lng - a.Lng) * PI() / 180.0 / 2.0) as SinHalfDeltaLngRad  
       ,cos(a.Lat) * cos(a.Lat)                   as CosCosLat           
    FROM hotels      as h
    cross JOIN attractions as a  
  ) t
) t
```

Yielding for your sample data:

```
Hotel_Name           Hotel_Address Attraction_Name      Attraction_Address DeltaRad               DeltaDeg               DeltaNMs               DeltaKMs
-------------------- ------------- -------------------- ------------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
HotelA               ST158DH       AttractionA          ST180BA            0.0018                 0.1                    6.02                   11.15
HotelB               ST161LF       AttractionA          ST180BA            0.0011                 0.06                   3.75                   6.94
HotelA               ST158DH       AttractionB          ST180TG            0.0015                 0.09                   5.2                    9.63
HotelB               ST161LF       AttractionB          ST180TG            0.0006                 0.03                   1.97                   3.64
```

Comment: Thank you Pieter, I will give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'SinHalfDeltaLatRad' in 'field list' 0.000 sec. Is this a MySQL issue Pieter? I'm not sure what the equivalent MySQL code would be, like you mentioned.

Comment: @user3694204: I bet MySQL doesn't understand the *Alias = Expression* syntax. Try rewriting with *Expression as Alias* syntax, which I believe is the ANSI standard.